# Pygame midi module init fails

Tags: python, pygame, midi

Working under Windows Seven.
I imported pygame 1.9.3 on a Python 3.6 in order to use the midi module.

The following lines :

```
import pygame
pygame.midi.init()
```

are raising a compiler error :"module pygame has no attribute midi"

Trying another module like "mixer" seems to work.

Is the midi module not present in the latest pygame library?
Any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import `midi` module as follows:

```
import pygame
import pygame.midi

pygame.midi.init()
```

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly import the midi module for it to work?

Comment: That did it !!
I do not need the rest of the pygame modules, so i made only a:

import. pygame.midi

And no more compiler errors.
Couldn't find any reference to that in the docs..

Thanks metmirr !